How to read data validation rules from an excel sheet using Python?
I have a template Excel sheet with some data validation rules that I need to populate with data from another source. I need to read the template Excel sheet with Python and populate the rows and then write it out while preserving the data validation rules that used to exist in the original excel sheet. The template is externally generated and I have no control over it, so I pretty much need to copy the validation rules from there.
I tried reading the Excel sheet in as an openpyxl workbook, but when checking the data validation on cells, they all seem to be empty.
import openpyxl

def main():
    wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('data_validation.xlsx')

    ws = wb2.active
    print(ws.data_validations)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

yields the output
<openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.DataValidationList object>
Parameters:
disablePrompts=None, xWindow=None, yWindow=None, count=0, dataValidation=[]

Where data_validation.xlsx is a placeholder for the template Excel sheet. For the purposes of a minimal reproducible example, it can be a simple two sheets Excel sheet with a dropdown validation on one of the cells where the dropdown values are read from another sheet inside the Excel workbook.
Sheet 1
|         |    A    |
|:-------:|:-------:|
|    1    |  Item 1 |
Sheet 2
|     |    A   |
|:---:|:------:|
|  1  | Item 1 |
|  2  | Item 3 |
|  3  | Item 3 |
With the validation rule.
Allow: List
Source: =Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3
An image representing the same example:

While reading in the workbook openpyxl does raise a warning.
UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed

So I'm assuming openpyxl doesn't support reading in pre-existing validation rules from an excel sheet? only populating it with new ones?
if that is the case, is there some other way to read in the validation rules? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

phoney_badger, this can help you: Openpyxl: Adding a sheet without removing data validation

"I'm assuming openpyxl doesn't support reading in pre-existing validation rules": It supports, but only for data valuations of types defined in Office Open XML version 2006 (used in Office 2007). There data validation lists cannot refer data in other sheets than the own. The data validation you are using is a type defined in Office Open XML version 2009 (used in Office 2010 and higher). That is not supported.
